# SQL Subquery in VB.Net with Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have developed an SQL query that uses sub-query based on a result set (i.e. a query queries the results of a sub-query). The query executes as expected in MS Access but will not execute in vb.net (including query builder). The error I receive in query builder is:

> Error in WHERE clause near 'ORDER'. Unable to parse query text.

I understand that a typical sub-query selects based on the `WHERE` clause whereas my SQL is querying based on the `FROM` clause. Because Access doesn't support the `LIMIT` command, I can't figure out how structure this SQL so it will run in VB.NET. If the `LIMIT` command was supported I think I could structure the sub-query properly.

Here is my SQL:

```sql
SELECT AVG(Differential) * .96
FROM            
   (SELECT TOP 5 Differential
    FROM            
      (SELECT TOP 10 GameDate, Differential
       FROM ScoringHistory
       WHERE PlayerID = ?
       ORDER BY GameDate DESC)
    ORDER BY Differential ASC, GameDate DESC)
```

If I change `PlayerID = ?` to `PlayerID = 1` (which is a valid value), query builder gives me the same error as above but I can execute the query in query builder.

I've also tried importing (`?`) the query from Access into VB.NET and I get the same error.

Any suggestions on how to structure my query so it will execute properly?

**Adding more information**:

I am implementing via a table adapter. See image.
[Selecting the query and clicking configure displays the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDnC.png)

Then if I click on the Query Builder button I get this error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhIrC.png)

My code to implement the query looks like this:

```
        Dim factor As Single
        factor = ScoringHistoryTableAdapter.CalculateFactor(1)
```

Comment: While I get the error in the query builder inside VS, it still produces the result. However, I do not get any errors in either Access or running the query using .ExecuteScalar(). All 3 methods return the same result from my test data. Can we see how you're setting up the query in the code to pass to the command?

Comment: This appears to be an incorrect parameterization setup in VB.Net and not an MS  Access SQL issue. It appears you can use named `@` params in [VB.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I am a novice at this so excuse what may be a strange implementation. 

I am implementing the SQL via a table adapter. I have created a query called "CalculateHandicap" that has the SQL contained within it.

Here is the code:
            Dim factor As Single
            factor = ScoringHistoryTableAdapter.CalculateFactor(1)

where "1" is a hard coded PlayerID (as a test for now).

And I agree that the query runs fine in Access.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing alis name or your subquery

```
SELECT AVG(Differential) * .96
FROM            
   (SELECT TOP 5 Differential
    FROM            
      (SELECT TOP 10 GameDate, Differential
       FROM ScoringHistory
       WHERE PlayerID = 1
       ORDER BY GameDate DESC) a
    ORDER BY Differential ASC, GameDate DESC) b
```

Comment: In MS Access SQL, alias names are randomly generated in background and will not error without them unless you reference an alias not assigned. Similarly if you use an expression in `SELECT` without an alias, Access will name it accordingly *Expr1*, *Expr2*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your OrderBy clauses are reversed.

You're ordering by GameDate in the middle From clause, but GameDate isn't included in that Select, only Differential.

Try:

```
    SELECT AVG(Differential) * .96
    FROM (
          SELECT TOP 5 Differential
          FROM (
                SELECT TOP 10 GameDate, Differential
                FROM ScoringHistory
                WHERE PlayerID = ?
                ORDER BY Differential ASC,GameDate DESC
               )
         ORDER BY Differential DESC
         )
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` fields do not have to be in `SELECT` clause. *GameDate* is in the scope of `TOP 5` query source.

Comment: Thanks Again but the revised query has the same error. And to be clear, it is the Table Adapter Query Configuration Wizard that is giving the error, "Error in WHERE clause near 'ORDER'.
Unable to parse query text."

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster I thought I would close the loop for everyone on this.

A little more research indicates that this is a known problem(?) with sub queries and the table adapter wizard. Now knowing this, i learned how to execute SQL the old fashioned way and used ExecuteScalar as Charles had indicated and the SQL works fine.